# How to prevent SQL injection when using raw SQL in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and web development. I'm using brakeman gem to identify security vulnerabilities in my site. One of the errors that came up was for SQL injection for the following sql code -

Possible SQL injection near line 109:

```
@resp_surveys = Response.connection.select_all("select q.survey_id, q.content      from questions q where survey_id IN (select survey_id from responses where user_id =#{session[:user_id]})")
```

I then modified the above SQL to the one given below and brakeman cleared this SQL injection error. The new SQL is given below -

```
resp_user_id= session[:user_id].to_i
@resp_surveys = Response.connection.select_all("select q.survey_id, q.content from questions q where survey_id IN (select survey_id from responses where user_id =#{resp_user_id})")
```

Could you please shed some light on this and let me know if this is the best way to write raw sql to prevent sql injection and if there is any other better way - as I need to rectify my other queries as well.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!